# Consulta MySQL anidada

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo tres tablas 
1. Tabla productos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Tabla almacen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.Tabla stock

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he podido crear una consulta que permita ver los productos con stock igual a cero de cada almacén
La respuesta debería ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA: Cuando stock de un producto es igual a cero NO existe en la tabla stock

Comment: No tienes ningún dato de la tabla stock en 0

Comment: Mas alla de lo que comenta @Pedro (esto podria ser solo un ejemplo, malo), que intentaste? porque esto con un group by y un having es simple

Comment: @gbianchi He utilizado LEFT JOIN Y RIGHT JOIN, sin embargo el resultado no es el esperado, la respuesta q quiero tener es : cuales productos tienen stock cero en cada almacen?, como lo harias con group by y un having?

Comment: Que probaste? que datos tenes de entrada? que recibiste? En que no funciono la respuesta que te dieron?

Comment: Cuando stock esta en cero, existe en la tabla stock?

Comment: cuando stock esta en cero, NO existe en la tabla stock, la respuesta de left join es cero filas

Comment: use las sentencias SELECT p.nombre, a.almacen, s.stock
FROM stock s
LEFT JOIN productos p ON p.rowid = s.producto
LEFT JOIN almacen a ON a.rowid = s.almacen
WHERE s.stock IS NULL OR s.stock = 0 y luego las modifique por RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas usar [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), para que todos los datos de las tablas se incluyan en tu consulta, incluso las que no aparezcan en la tabla stock o que tengan valor 0.

```
SELECT p.nombre, a.almacen, s.stock
FROM stock s
LEFT JOIN productos p ON p.rowid = s.producto
LEFT JOIN almacen a ON a.rowid = s.almacen
WHERE s.stock IS NULL OR s.stock = 0
```

Comment: Podrias mirar [answer]? la respuesta tiene que estar un poco mas explicada y no ser solo codigo (y en tu caso un link)